# Can I email Tax Payer Certificate to Embassy of Netherlands after submission

Tags: schengen-visas, netherlands, pakistan, vfs-global

I have submitted a Business Schengen Visa application via VFS yesterday Lahore, Pakistan. Due to the change in policy in terms of documentation. The VFS assistant refused to take Tax Returns Papers and some of my previous visa's copy and told me that now it is not required for Netherlands Visa.

As I usually don't submit an Active Tax Payer certificate in Visa Applications, because the Tax Returns documents are a proof that I'm an active tax payer in Pakistan. Now I think I failed to provide sufficient information in the application that Im an active tax payers. Because they did not allow me to attach the proof. They allowed me to attach the online certificate but I was unable to avail the certificate at the time of submission.

Now Can I email my active taxpayer proof to the Netherlands embassy in Islamabad, Pakistan?

Comment: what is the purpose of your visit to the Netherlands? It depends up on those too.

Comment: My purpose is to join a meeting with my employer. I also did visit them last year.